# Leave point in original position when C-g is pressed?

Tags: region, point, mark, quitting

I am writing a function to select a region (say 2 lines).

```
(defun select-some-region ()
  (interactive)
    (push-mark (point) nil t)
      (forward-line 2))
```

When point is in a buffer like this

```
 |this is first
 this is second
 this is third
```

If I run `M-x select-some-region` it will select two line and I press `C-g` it will deselect the region but leaves point somewhere else like this.

```
 this is first
 this is second
 |this is third
```

How can I leave point in actual position where it was before when `C-g` is pressed?

**Update:**

In my actual `select-some-regions`  function, I have to select few  lines before point and few lines after point.

Comment: You could just perform point movement in reverse order. I.e. forward line first, while remembering where the point was before you moved, and then push mark to the position you remembered.

Comment: Excatly, but how can i detect that user has pressed `C-g`?

Comment: There's a fairly new package `smart-mark` added to Melpa. That might do what you want.

Comment: @kaushalmodi You can post it as solution as it solves the problem. That package is using `advice-add` but i guess there are much better solutions as packages like `exapand-region`, `web-mode` do the same without advice.

Comment: @ChillarAnand Actually `smart-mark` package might not be applicable here as you would need to customize the `smart-mark-mark-functions` var and add every function in there for which you need the "smart mark" functionality. I use the package to resolve one minor annoyance: Doing `C-x h` and restoring mark after `C-g`. The advices in that package have not harmed me in any way till now so I wouldn't say that that approach is not better :) It's great as it works for me right out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through web-mode source code, i found this solution.

Store initial point in some  variable in function. Write a function which moves point to that location  when  `C-g` is pressed. Now hook this function to `post-command-hook`

```el
(defun select-some-region ()
  (interactive)
  (setq initial-pos (point))
  (push-mark (point) nil t)
  (forward-line 2))    

(defun move-point ()
  (when (eq this-command 'keyboard-quit)
    (goto-char initial-pos)))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'move-point)
```

Comment: I think the `exapand-region` package used a similar method, although they adviced `keyboard-quit` and `cua-cancel` instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can this help?

```el
(defun select-some-region ()
  (interactive)
   (let ((this-point (point))) (forward-line 2)  (push-mark (point) nil t)
      (goto-char this-point) ))
```

Comment: (idea suggested by @wvxvw)

Comment: This is good. I  am  actually trying to select few lines  before point and few  lines after point, so  this doesn't work in [required context](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/pull/617/files#diff-a01b1e451c8b56727a075f934b1aad0cR1676)

Answer (score 1):

The function `keyboard-quit` is just a few lines of code in `simple.el`, which can either be redefined or otherwise tweaked/modified to suit the user's needs.  The following answer uses `defacvice`:  If beginning of the region is less than point, this means that the region was marked from left to right, so go to the beginning of the region.  If not, the region was marked from right to left, so go to the end of the region.

```lisp
(defadvice keyboard-quit (before keyboard-quit-before activate)
  (when (region-active-p)
    (let* (
        (pt (point))
        (beg (region-beginning))
        (end (region-end)) )
      (if (< beg pt)
        (goto-char beg)
        (goto-char end)))))
```

Comment: Redefining `keyboard-quit` *seems* (to me) like a particularly dodgy idea. I'd be curious to hear a maintainer's opinion on doing this. I wouldn't recommend it, but that's mostly gut instinct.

Comment: @phils -- the majority of Emacs users treat the source-code as *sacred/holy* -- i.e., it is a cult following -- but I think in terms of *blasphemy* in that it's just plain code to be manipulated as I see fit.  I have custom functions for just about everything that I use on a daily basis, including `keyboard-quit` and `keyboard-escape-quit` -- I have custom `files`, custom `dired`, custom `tramp`, custom `org`, custom `calendar`, custom `tex`, custom `elisp-mode`, custom `wanderlust` and related libraries, custom just about everything . . . :)

Comment: I agree with @phils : I don't think it's so much blind obedience to dogma, but rather that if you modify fundamental functions the knock-on effects could be wide-ranging and unpredictable. Once you start editing primitives you will make it very hard for anyone else to help you isolate and correct problems arising as unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

`C-g` does not move the point, so there's no “original position” to restore. If you want the `select-some-region` function to preserve the point, write it in such a way that it does preserve the point. With the function in your question, you could invert the point and the mark.

```el
(defun select-some-region ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (forward-line 2)
    (push-mark (point) nil t)))
```

Alternatively, given your original function, you can easily return to the previous cursor position, since the mark is set there. Just press `C-1 C-SPC` (`set-mark-command` with the numeric argument 1).

Comment: I guess this will not work, when i want to select two lines before & two lines after cursor?

Comment: @ChillarAnand No, because in Emacs, the cursor is one of the boundaries of the selection, there's only one mark, not two like in Wordstar.

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned, `C-g` does not move point by itself. You mentioned in a comment that the region you sets started before and ended after the current point position, hence you can not use the trick of keeping point where it is.

I think one way of dealing with this problem is to push mark at current position before marking the region. Then you can recover the previous point position by hitting `C-u C-SPC` twice. Example with `mark-paragraph` :

```
(defun my/mark-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (push-mark nil t)
  (call-interactively 'mark-paragraph))
```